# Counting results returned within php, efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

Technologies in use: php accessing MySQL via PDO.

I have the following query:

```
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $database.appsLodged WHERE `uID` = :uid");
        $stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
```

Which is fairly straight forward. At the moment there are 7 rows in the relevant database, and each one can potentially have a different string value returned for $result[0][5]. I would like to be able to count how many results there are that have a $result[0][5] of "shoes and socks" and then how many have a $result[0][5] of "boots and skirts" and how many have a $result[0][5] of "jumpers and cardigans" - without having to resort to doing multiple database queries (I know we can do it by adding an additional "AND `item` = :item" syntax and binding :item to "shoes and socks", but this seems very repetitive and unnecessary.

Suggestions please, all welcome! :)

C

As requested below, here is the $result array listed:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Pending
        [5] => Pending
        [dateStarted] => 1421773018
        [6] => 1421773018
        [lastModified] => 1421773018
        [7] => 1421773018
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1421774389
        [6] => 1421774389
        [lastModified] => 1421774389
        [7] => 1421774389
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [0] => 3
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1421776146
        [6] => 1421776146
        [lastModified] => 1421776146
        [7] => 1421776146
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [0] => 4
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1421777460
        [6] => 1421777460
        [lastModified] => 1421777460
        [7] => 1421777460
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [0] => 5
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1421781756
        [6] => 1421781756
        [lastModified] => 1421781756
        [7] => 1421781756
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [0] => 6
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422213946
        [6] => 1422213946
        [lastModified] => 1422213946
        [7] => 1422213946
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [0] => 7
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422238026
        [6] => 1422238026
        [lastModified] => 1422238026
        [7] => 1422238026
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [0] => 8
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422369458
        [6] => 1422369458
        [lastModified] => 1422369458
        [7] => 1422369458
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [0] => 9
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422369473
        [6] => 1422369473
        [lastModified] => 1422369473
        [7] => 1422369473
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [0] => 10
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422371233
        [6] => 1422371233
        [lastModified] => 1422371233
        [7] => 1422371233
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [0] => 11
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422371291
        [6] => 1422371291
        [lastModified] => 1422371291
        [7] => 1422371291
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [0] => 12
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422372793
        [6] => 1422372793
        [lastModified] => 1422372793
        [7] => 1422372793
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [0] => 13
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422373414
        [6] => 1422373414
        [lastModified] => 1422373414
        [7] => 1422373414
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [0] => 14
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422373681
        [6] => 1422373681
        [lastModified] => 1422373681
        [7] => 1422373681
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [0] => 15
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422373927
        [6] => 1422373927
        [lastModified] => 1422373927
        [7] => 1422373927
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [0] => 16
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422374004
        [6] => 1422374004
        [lastModified] => 1422374004
        [7] => 1422374004
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [id] => 17
        [0] => 17
        [appID] => 4
        [1] => 4
        [applicationKey] => ConSupAp
        [2] => ConSupAp
        [applicationName] => Conference Support Application
        [3] => Conference Support Application
        [uID] => 1
        [4] => 1
        [status] => Data Acquisition
        [5] => Data Acquisition
        [dateStarted] => 1422374587
        [6] => 1422374587
        [lastModified] => 1422374587
        [7] => 1422374587
    )

)
```

Important to remember - it is actually the 'status' column I am wanting to count which for all of these examples except the first, is set to "Data Acquisition". The first is set to "Pending". There are another three values this could be, and if these are not in the database at the time I need a zero count for them so the user knows they have zero data set to other potential 'status' settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following: first of all, you take from you database all those strings, so you will have something like `$result[0][5]`, `$result[1][5]`, `$result[2][5]` and so on, then you `foreach()` them and match the strings in different variables, one for each string you want to match... I think, based on what you said in you query, that each uID has one type of string in the [5] position. In witch case, I advice you have a string of id's, so your query becomes something like this:

```
$uid = '1,2,3,4,5'; // for example
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $database.appsLodged WHERE `uID` IN (:uid)");

$stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
```

you will probably need one extra query to take all those ids but that's about it :D

Hope this helps!

Comment: for the correct query, please check the edited version of my response :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so quick as well! I'm sorry I was not clear about the $uid value - this never changes as it is the user ID and so will only pull rows from the db table that are related to that particular user. It doesn't change and so is not relevant to the actual question.

Comment: But how do you have multiple values in $result[0][5] then? do you repeat this query foreach user?

Comment: It is done on an account basis so each user will only need to see what data rows are relevant to them. The value that $result[0][5] - which is actually a column named "item" can be one of five possible string values. I need to count how many of each of the values there are.

Comment: foreach user, right? then it's easier then I expected :D why? because you have a foreach that runs trough all your users. You just need to make a variable for each of those values that you search for, and when you encounter in that position a given string, you increment that variable. At the end of the foreach, you will have all strings counted and accounted for :)

Comment: No not for each user - this is to display a result on a page that a single user sees once they have logged in, so they just need to see a count of each row that is relevant to them and no one else. They need to see how many rows relating to them that have "shoes and boots" as the $result[0][5] value, and so on for each of the possible values. They also need to know if they have zero for any potential options, also.

Comment: could you please update you question with a relevant $result array? it will make a lot more sense this way :D

Comment: It's really easy then... foreach that big array that you have up there and match the strings in different variables, one for each string you want to match... and that's it :)